Safe to manually delete Google Artifact Registry images from already-deployed Firebase Cloud Functions functions?
When deploying Firebase Cloud Functions functions through the Firebase CLI, I am often met with the following error:

functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result
in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete
these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/some-project-ID/us/gcf

The functions are properly deployed but some artifacts remain. In the gcf-artifacts folder that one can access in Google Cloud console, the one that the error message is pointing to, is the CLI telling us that it's safe to delete all of the images in there that are the cache folders for these specific cloud functions, or is it more nuanced than that? For example, if I deploy a function named "someCloudFunction" and I am met with this error, is it safe then to delete "someCloudFunction/cache" outright from the artifact repository in console?

You can delete them, though you should consider contacting Firebase support to report the problem, as this error shouldn't happen. The CLI should be able to clean up.
